# Facebook Android SDK — no 'email' in meRequest

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm using the following code to get user's email:

```
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                          // Obtaining 
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
```

The following is checked via debugger:

- AccessToken instance contains permissions "email" and "public_profile"
- AccessToken instance declined permissions set is empty
- Resulting JSONObject contains only user id and name, but no email

Profile has email — I'm authenticating via email.

I'm using Facebook SDK 4.5

**EDIT**: Request via direct HTTP graph api call returns email. But Android SDK does not.

How to fix it?

Comment: Profile that you are using for tests is real profile? Is it associated and confirmed by real phone number?

Comment: @AlexeyKorolev, I've tested with real (mine) profile and with test "bot" profiles. Both of them are without phone numbers. Also, see edit.

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, “declarative fields”

Comment: Any news? i have the same issue..

Answer (score 2):

Try this out, you need to send "email" as part of parameters for `GraphRequest`.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(
                                        JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                                }
                            });

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the user can specify no email permissions when he/she signs in via facebook. So even if you expect it, you might not get the email address.

Comment: Yes, I know that (and ready for this case), but I've tested with two mine own profiles and never restricted email access for this app. Also, pls see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we facing same problem, try this :

```
Bundle params=new Bundle();
params.putString("fields","id,name,email,verified"); //must specify the "fields" param, otherwise FB always return id and name only.
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/me",
    params,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        //do something...
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```